# How to change working directory for eclipse run configuration programmaticaly?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to change this directory programmatically in runtime:

[image]

I need in because I work with some files which are needed for the plugin. But these files can't be found in `System32` folder. When I change this working directory here in preferences everything works well. I tried to use this code:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "some_address");
```

then I check that the folder was changed:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

but the program also continues crashing due to missed files also after folder change via the code above. Maybe I have to set this field value in another way? Or maybe Eclipse has some keys which can be set?

Comment: It is not clear exactly where you are running that code. An Eclipse plug-in can change the working directory of in a launch configuration using the Launch APIs which are described in the "Program debug and launch support" section of the "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide" in the Eclipse help.

Comment: I'm running this code in the class which is assigned to my plug-in, and also in this class I try to work with files from working directory. That is why I'm asking about it, thank you for the guide, I will check it and maybe it will help me :)

Comment: An Eclipse plug-in will have whatever working directory was active when Eclipse was started, you can't change that. It sounds like you need to find a different way to locate the files.

Comment: yes I saw also it in the eclipse help web site. But I don't have any solution how to do it, which details you need? I tried to change this working directory preference via the code above, but it didn't help me :(

Comment: Why can't you just use absolute paths to the files instead of relative paths? [edit] your question and add more details about what you are trying to do.